# How to change this javascript only to use only 1 button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
function show(page) {
var html = "";
switch (page) {
    case "home":
        html = 'All the stuff of the page  ';
        break;
    case "about":
        html = 'All the stuff of the pahe';
        break;
    case "contact":
        html = "This is the contact page<br />...";
        break;
}

document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = html;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/z2UCX/5/

'about' link goes to the about and 'contacts' link to the contacts. How to make this working using only one link/button/image so a single button will cycle through everything. Let's we have 'button left' instead of 'home' link here. It should keep cycling link infinitely.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could just use a basic counter.  Something like:

```
var cnt = 0;
function show() {
  var html = "";
  switch (cnt) {
    case 0: html = "All the stuff of the page "; break;
    case 1: html = "All the stuff of the page"; break;
    case 2: html = "This is the contact page<br />..."; break;
  }
  document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = html;
  cnt = (cnt+1)%3;
}
```

Then in your link, you'll call this function: `show();`

Answer (score 0):

Just need add

```
var position = 0;
var list_page = new Array("home", "about", "contact");

function next_page() { 
    position = (++position)%list_page.length;   
    show(list_page[position]);
}
```

Example : http://jsfiddle.net/z2UCX/10/